# SQLDataReader not returning rows/populating list

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to return all rows of a single column in my database to populate a list. When I execute the stored procedure in SQL, it works fine, but nothing gets returned when I try to do it in C#.

```
public static List<string> GetRows(string filter_one, string filter_two)
{
    var retrievedRows = new List<string>();
    var storedProc = "dbo.MyStoredProc";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MY_CONNECTION_STRING))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProc, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@FilterOne", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter_one;
        command.Parameters.Add("@FilterTwo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter_two;
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                retrievedRows.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    return retrievedRows;
}
```

Any ideas? I get no errors in the console or when I run it on IIS Express either. When I watch retrievedRows, the size stays at 0 even though when I run the same query in SQL with the same passed parameters, it returns results for me.

EDIT: Please excuse me, my brain must be running a bit slow today. One of the parameters I was passing was pointed at the (empty) value of the wrong webcontrol. I don't know how I missed this.

Comment: Are you using the exact same values for `filter_one` and `filter_two` as used in the stored procedure to return records?

Comment: Also, if you put a breakpoint on the line where it's adding records (`retrievedRows.Add(reader.GetString(0));`), does it stop execution there?

Comment: You need to show us your SP definition, at least the parameters and the return part.

Comment: have you tried specifying parameter direction? parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one issue with your posted snippet that I can see, which could pose a problem:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@FilterOne", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter_one;
command.Parameters.Add("@FilterTwo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter_two;
```

In this section, you're adding two `VARCHAR` parameters but not specifying a length for them. Try changing your code to add a length specification:

```
var filterOne = new SqlParameter("FilterOne", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
```

The constructor in use here is [`SqlParameter(string, SqlDbType, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_System_Int32_):

> Parameters
> -
>
> parameterName (String): The name of the parameter to map.
>
> dbType (SqlDbType): One of the SqlDbType values.
>
> size (Int32): The length of the parameter.

When working with `VARCHAR` you must specify a length or anything outside of the default length (which is 1 byte for definitions and variables, and 30 bytes for `CAST` and `CONVERT`) [will be truncated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If n isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Comment: Edited my post, although thank you for the response! I didn't know that you needed to specify the length for the parameters you add. Helpful to know!

Comment: @BryanTran glad to be of service and help a fellow developer out! My apologies if my initial verbiage sounded a bit blunt or negative, it wasn't meant that way at all. Also, welcome-ish to Stack Overflow! 